How to handle definitions in professional philosophic/scientific contexts?
So I had multiple instances, where a word in a paper or similar had to be defined.
In the past, I employed or was thinking of employing various techniques to go about defining a certain word e.g.:

I defined it myself. This had the advantage that I could control the meaning of the word. The disadvantages were that readers might not agree with my definition or that my definition might have been nonsense.
I would use Wikipedia. The advantage could be here that a Wikipedia definition would be the most commonly used in society. The Disadvantage would be that anything Wikipedia-related is frowned upon.
I used a definition from another professional author. Here the advantage is that the authoritative argument can be used if that person is important enough. The disadvantage is that often these definitions try to specify a specific meaning, that makes perfect sense in the context of their problem/paper but does not apply to mine or doesn't convey the meaning I want to convey.
I would use ChatGPT (I haven't yet). The Advantage is that ChatGPT is quite good at phrasing a definition. The Disadvantage is that it is from ChatGPT and it is similar to if I would have defined it myself.

So I was wondering: If a word had to be defined in a professional philosophic/scientific context, how would you proceed to define it, what sources should be used and what has to be done to defend that definition?

Doesn't this depend on the profession in question? But DIY, Wikipedia and ChatGPT are typically pretty bad ideas. How would you know if the 'definition' is what was intended if you DIY it? For philosophy, Stanford Encyclopedia and academic textbooks are much more preferable, but still insufficient. When it comes to specific authors there are often nuances that one can spot only by inspecting their own works and academic commentary on them. Other philosophers may well use the same word very differently.

Sounds like a question for [workplace.se]. I'm not seeing the link to philosophy (except maybe if you were a philosopher, but that doesn't seem to be the case). Although different workplace contexts may have different norms. But you could construct a definition using some combination of any or all of these, depending on how people would commonly understand the term and how you're using it (it wouldn't help much to define it in one way and then you go on to use it in a completely different way).

@NotThatGuy Guess I will scope it to professional philosophic/scientific contexts. Or is science already out of scope here for this question?

@telion Professional scientific contexts are typically within [academia.se] (they have a ton of questions relating to definitions in academic papers) and sometimes also [workplace.se] - not sure that would really fit here. Questions relating to writing philosophy papers may also fit well on [academia.se], at least or especially if the question doesn't specifically relate to philosophical concepts.

When and how to introduce definitions, what their purpose is in debates, what their limitations are, is a topic both in logic and meta-logic, in the methodology of particular sciences and other activities (like law), in any kind of general theory of argumentation, and thus, also, in general, in philosophy. As evidence for this you could consider that Arne Naess in his Elementary Theory of Argumentation (En del elementaere logiske emmer) spends a whole chapter on "definitions".
The word "definition" itself is used in various contexts - both everyday and technical - and can lead to misunderstandings. In general, a definition of a word or phrase may be needed, if there is otherwise a possibility of misunderstanding. In this general context, the purpose of giving a "definition" is to clarify or make more precise what you mean by that word or phrase. So, you posit to your public that a particular word, phrase, or statement, should be interpreted, in the context at hand, as equal to another word, phrase or statement. (This is a loose paraphrase of what Naess calls "rule-giving definitions").
If this is also what you had in mind when asking about definitions, you will see that the source of a definition is totally irrelevant. What is relevant is only that you (try to) clarify how you intend to use your words -- in a particular context, and for a particular public.
